# Equations with 2 mods

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have 4 equations with mods and I need to find the params to build the function $h(x)$. Is there a method to find these?

$h(x) = ((ax + b)$ mod $c) $mod $3$

$h(0) = 0$;

$h(1) = 2$;

$h(2) = 1$;

$h(3) = 0$;

Thanks

Comment: Example, $a=2,b=0$ and $c=3$.

Comment: How do you find them?. Just testing values?

Comment: $c=3$ is something to start, first and last condition says $b$ is not necessary, and then it follows $a=2$.

Comment: Problem is there are infinitely many values that fit the data.